# How to put empty set in inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a complete beginner in MySql and I wanted you to help me. I want a `DTR User Interface` where there is time in and time out. So I have a fields like -`id_biometrics,empno,datecreated,time_created,status,device` the problem is if the employee forgot to time in or time out, I want to put the time in or time out to "NULL" here is what I coded.

```
SELECT start_log.empno AS "Employee Number", start_log.date_created, start_log.time_created AS "Time In", end_log.time_created AS "Time Out"    
FROM biometrics AS start_log
INNER JOIN biometrics AS end_log ON start_log.empno = end_log.empno
WHERE start_log.status =0
AND end_log.status =1
AND start_log.empno =2
GROUP BY start_log.date_created, start_log.empno
```

And what my output here if he completes his time in and time out for the day is.

```
Employee Number|date_created |Time_in   | Time_Out
             2 | 2013-07-15  | 11:08:07 | 15:00:00
```

And if he/she forgots to Time Out or time in it shows MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0016 sec )

What I wanted is

```
Employee Number | date_created |Time_in   | Time_Out
         3      | 2013-07-15   | 11:50:00 | Null
```

Please help me with this. I needed it badly thanks.

Comment: Consider providing a sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH YOUR DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: @Strawberry No need to shout.

Comment: @Strawberry what do you mean?

Comment: Michael, if there's some part of my comment that google cannot answer, please specify what that it is and I'll attempt to clarify my response.

Comment: @Strawberry Are sqlfiddles perminant? I'm thinking about the long term usefulness of the question

Comment: I've no idea. But once the ddls are there, it's easy (and probably sensible) enough to add them to the original question.

Comment: can't try it now but guessing you need this: "SELECT ..., IFNULL(end_log.time_created, 'value you want if null') AS "Time Out"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT empno, date_created, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN time_created END) time_in,
       MIN(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN time_created END) time_out
  FROM biometrics
 GROUP BY empno, date_created
```

Sample output:

```
+-------+--------------+----------+----------+
| empno | date_created | time_in  | time_out |
+-------+--------------+----------+----------+
|     2 | 2013-07-15   | 11:08:07 | 15:00:00 |
|     3 | 2013-07-15   | 11:50:00 | NULL     |
|     4 | 2013-07-15   | NULL     | 16:00:00 |
+-------+--------------+----------+----------+
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4ae9/1)** demo

**UPDATE** If you may have multiple in or out records and you always want to fetch first in and last out then just use `MAX()` aggregate for `time_out`

```
SELECT empno, date_created, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN time_created END) time_in,
       MAX(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN time_created END) time_out
  FROM biometrics
 GROUP BY empno, date_created
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a9b7/1)** demo

Comment: thank you sir. helped me alot what if i wanted a data that has a 1 Time in and 2 time out and i wanted to print the first in and last out?

Comment: @MichaelSo You're very welcome :) See updated answer for a solution.

Comment: sorry for a noob question but how about if i want to calculate the hour of his/her working time in a specific day?

Comment: what if i want to compute for the overtime for a specific day sir @peterm ?

Comment: @MichaelSo Your follow up questions go far beyond your original question and it's not very welcome here on SO. If you have other questions you better put them together, provide relevant sample data and desired output and post an additional question with a link to the previous one. Then other SO members or I will be happy to answer it.

Comment: im sorry sir. i posted it already. here is the link sir. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667613/mysql-counting-overtime-per-hour

Comment: @MichaelSo Now to give an idea: to calculate working ours you could subtract `time_in` from `time_out`, but you need to provide default values for cases when values are `NULL`s. You can do that with `COALESCE` function. To calculate overtime you'll need to subtract working hours from const value of normal working hours per day.

Comment: @MichaelSo I provided [a possible solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17667815/1920232) for your new question. Check it out and let me know.