# Calculate overtime per day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an sql code that gets the total work hours of each employee and his time in time out. I want to compute the total overtime of his work for the day. Can you help me with this? 8 hours is the regular hour per day.

Here is the codes

```
SELECT
  empno,
  date_created,
  time_in,
  time_out,
  time_format(timediff(time_out, time_in), '%H:%i') AS total_time
FROM
(
  SELECT empno, date_created,
    min(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN time_created END) time_in,
    max(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN time_created END) time_out
  FROM biometrics
  WHERE empno = 3
  GROUP BY empno, date_created
) t1;
```

---

SAMPLE OUTPUT

```
empno| date_created | time_in | time_out
  2      2013-07-15   11:08:07  15:00:00
  3      2013-07-15   11:50:00  NULL
  4      2013-07-15    NULL     16:00:00
```

---

What i want is something like this

```
empno | date_created | time_in | time_out | overtime
 2       2013-07-15    5:00:00  15:00:00      2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
SELECT empno, date_created, time_in, time_out, 
       CASE WHEN total_hours - 8 > 0 THEN total_hours - 8 ELSE 0 END overtime
  FROM
(
  SELECT empno, date_created, time_in, time_out,
         TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(COALESCE(time_out, '17:00:00'),
                              COALESCE(time_in,  '09:00:00'))) / 3600 total_hours
    FROM
  (
    SELECT empno, date_created, 
           MIN(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN time_created END) time_in,
           MIN(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN time_created END) time_out
      FROM biometrics
     GROUP BY empno, date_created
  ) a
) b
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d324e/2)** demo

You need to provide real default values for `time_in` and `time_out` for cases when they are `NULL`. In an extreme case if `NULL`s are caused by the fact that employees come one day and go home the other day those default values might be `00:00:00` and `23:59:59` respectively since you are calculating overtime per calendar day.

**UPDATE:** if you want `overtime` to be presented in time format

```
SELECT empno, date_created, time_in, time_out, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(
         CASE WHEN total_sec - 28800 > 0 
              THEN total_sec - 28800 
              ELSE 0 END) overtime
  FROM
(
  SELECT empno, date_created, time_in, time_out,
         TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(COALESCE(time_out, '17:00:00'),
                              COALESCE(time_in,  '09:00:00'))) total_sec
    FROM
  (
    SELECT empno, date_created, 
           MIN(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN time_created END) time_in,
           MIN(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN time_created END) time_out
      FROM biometrics
     GROUP BY empno, date_created
  ) a
) b
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d324e/6)** demo

Comment: oh! dont know how can i thank you. thank you just what i am looking for. ive been searching all over net for this. @peterm

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IFNULL(TIMEDIFF('08:00:00',(TIMEDIFF(time_out,time_in))),0) 
AS OVERTIME
FROM biometrics
```